# Multiple character encoding in Magento

Tags: magento, encoding

I had a problem with Chinese character imports before, it was fixed when I changed my database charset to utf8 and collation utf8_general_ci

Now I am importing European translations(Italian, German, French, etc.) but the accent letters are changing into question marks...

Any workaround to fit two charsets?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're seeing with accent letters doesn't have anything to do with the change you made in your database. The 'utf8_general_ci' collation is the correct one for a Magento website, so you've properly set everything up.

Importing new translations into a Magento website consists of uploading a bunch of CSV files into a path under the root Magento installation folder, in app/locale/[some_locale_code] or to the locale folder under one of your active themes.

Problems with question marks instead of accent characters are usually the result of editing these CSV files in MS Excel, or in notepad, and saving them without regard to the chosen encoding. Re-open the original file, and make sure to save it with as UTF8. Then, re-upload those files to your Magento installation folder.

Here are the instructions on how to save the file properly, taken from the [Magento official wiki on translation files](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/166/useful_tools_to_work_with_translations):

> Most people miss the way to save UTF-8 with Excel. Choose Save As...
>   from the file menu and then on the Save As dialog box, look for an
>   item called Tools with a little downwards tick beside it. Click it and
>   a dropdown menu opens with one of the selections being Web Options...
>   Select and on the next dialog box that opens up select the tab
>   Encoding. Set your encoding to UTF-8, OK back to the Save As dialog
>   box, make sure your Save as type: under the file name is CSV and save
>   your file.

Alternatively, you could use an external extension to handle this work for you:
1. [Content Translator and Localizor](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/content-translator-and-localizer.html)
2. [Translations Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/translations-manager.html) (of which I am the author)